# Is consume a client web service from web browser good practice?

Tags: .net, angular, web-services, client, peripherals

I'm developing a web application and I need to consume a service from the client side. I will deploy the service on the client and consume it from the web browser with Angular. Is this good practice?

I need to deploy the service on the client because the user needs to interact with peripherals on the web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Consuming web services through the browsers is a pretty standard practice most of the platforms now use some sort of REST APIs.

**Security Considerations**
Depending on the complexity and criticality of the application you would want to consider implementing a security framework. Check out oAuth2, open-id-connect & https

https://restfulapi.net/security-essentials/

**Hosting Infrastructure**
Both AWS and Azure provide framework for authentication and authorisation frameworks

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/choose-ad-authn

You could also consider one of a third part services such as

https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/09/04/securing-rest-apis

Finally most hosting services will also recommend you to implement https.

BR